# Upgrade gcc toolchain in host

Tags: gcc, arm, toolchain

We use arm (cortex a8), and need to upgrade gcc in host (from 4.3 to above 4.9.2, so that it support c++11).

Is it just a matter of changing the toolchain in host or do we need to update the root filesystem with the new glibc ?

Host: x86 computer where we do the cross compilation for arm

Traget: arm cortex a8

Comment: define host.  you can have as many installed gcc toolchains as you have storage space for, set your path to point to one and just use it...but what operating system you have how you want to install them where you want to get them, etc can vary.

Comment: define: host     ...

Comment: host: the computer where we do the cross compilation for the arm target. It's compile from intel x86 to arm. see the question

Comment: okay thanks, then yes you can have as many toolchains and versions as you want (not that you couldnt on the target machine), or at least space for,  just install them and use them.

Comment: as far as the root filesystem what does the host file system have to do with compiling for the target.  And same goes for glibc, point your library paths to the glibc you want and/or use the one that is bundled with the toolchain (or built with it if you choose to build your toolchain rather than download and extract/install one)

Comment: where did you get and install your current toolchain?

Comment: you need not to update anything except some binutils.. Just download the cross toolchain which supports gcc-4.9.2 and setup environment to use this cross tool chain in your project to build.

Comment: why there is need for binutils ? isn't it only that the new glibc should be copied to target ? Is there any tutorial on this ?

Comment: I use codesourcery arm-2009q1-203